# Select class - onChange test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Writing an unit test using JEST JS and Enzyme.
Code has a few select classes with value set to different state.

For example :
I am able to find the following :

```
<Select
   disabled={disabled}
   className={showRequired(checkRequired, this.state.AccountStatus, 'value') ? 'account-select req' : 'account-select'}
   id='custodian-status'
   value={this.state.AccountStatus}
   onChange={(e) => {let val = e ? e.value : null; this.setState({AccountStatus: e})}}
   options={this.state.AccountStatusOptions}
/>
```

But unable to find this for example:

```
{ type === 'add' &&  
  <div className='account-info-item'>
     <label className='label'>Base Currency:</label>
      <Select
       disabled={disabled}
       className={showRequired(checkRequired, this.state.BaseCurrency, 'value') ? 'account-select req' : 'account-select'}
       id='custodian-status'
       value={this.state.BaseCurrency}
       onChange={(e) => {let val = e ? e.value : null; this.setState({BaseCurrency: e})}}
       options={this.state.BaseCurrencyOptions}
     />
   </div>
   }
```

Here is my beforeEach condition:

```
   beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}><AccountForm {...baseProps} /></MemoryRouter>));
```

here is how I am trying to find its node:

```
 wrapper.find('AccountForm').find('Select').props('').onChange(#custodian-status)
```

error:  Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 4 found instead. Select is being called 9 times and not 4.

Also tried the following:

```
wrapper.find('AccountForm').find('Select').find('custodian-status').simulate('change')
```

error: Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Answer (score 1):

The find method can get any element rendered on mounted tree. And simulate needs a event type, and a event object. You can just do:

```
wrapper.find('Select').simulate('change', {target { value : 'foo'}})
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had before , but I found out why I couldn't find the other select

Comment: I forgot to add on my set state: type: 'add' , now I'm able to see 9 select nodes

Comment: actually I'm not able to find using simulate , this one works for me :    wrapper.find('AccountForm').find('Select').props().onChange({target: {value: 'test'}}

Comment: Oh! I have forgotten to delete `.find('AccountForm')`, it's not necessary to chain the tree. But I'm glad you could solve your problem.

Comment: It was  just a setstate missing, dats all. But thanks anyway